# What's the closest to an enum in maya native nodes? (2020)

Tags: nodes, maya

I have a list of integer values that I'd like to have as inputs and with a switch attribute be able to output any of my integer values depending on the value of switch attribute.
Example:

Node receives as inputs:

```
plug [0]: 1
plug [1]: 5
plug [2]: 3
```

If my switch attribute on said node is 0, the output is 1, if switch is 1, output is 5, and so on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As a note, something like floatCondition doesn't work as I need many attributes instead of just 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of get away with this using an expression node. Here's a little example that sets up an expression on a locator (look at the additional attributes in the Attribute editor).

```cpp
$locator = `spaceLocator`;

// add an array of values (I assume you have already added this attribute?)
addAttr -ln "array_values" -at long -multi -k true $locator;

// set a few values for fun
setAttr ($locator[0] + ".array_values[0]") 1;
setAttr ($locator[0] + ".array_values[1]") 5;
setAttr ($locator[0] + ".array_values[2]") 3;

// create an attribute to control which integer is output
addAttr -ln "array_index" -at long -k true $locator;

// create an attribute to hold the result
addAttr -ln "output_value" -at long -k true $locator;

// I want to create the expression:
//
//  output_value = array_values[array_index]
//
// However, I can't directly reference array attributes by name 
// in an expression, so I need to reference them via getAttr. 
// I effectively want to construct an expression that does this:
//
//   output_value = `getAtr "locator1.array_values[array_index]"`
//
// However that will need some additional string escaping to get there.... 
//
string $expressionString = "output_value = `getAttr (\"" + $locator[0] + ".array_values[\" + array_index + \"]\")`";

// create the expression
expression -s ($expressionString) -o $locator[0] -ae 1 -uc all;
```

There is however one caveat to be aware of here!

For an expression to correctly update within a DG compute step, the attributes must be named (attributes referenced with getAttr cannot trigger a recompute). So `output_value` will happily update when `array_index` changes, however it will not change value if the array elements change *(only when the array_index is again changed later)*

If you need the changes to array elements to be automatically updated, you'll probably need to add a custom node in the API. (derive from MPxNode, add 3 long values, where your array attributes has setArray(true). Specify the dependencies with attributeAffects.

For the compute method, you can grab the output value and index direct from the data handles. For the array data, you'll need to grab the array element by using an MArrayDataHAndle. That should fix the update problem...